# Combination of SQL prepared statement and str_replace() - is it safe?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

This code checks if a form input value is not empty, and if so - updates the relevant MySql column of the relevant row (id).

Is the `str_replace()` operated on the prepared statement (for looping through columns) makes it vulnerable?

Is this code safe? Is there a better option?

```
// get submitted form values
$ids = $_POST['ids_edit_mult'];    
$exhibition_he = $_POST['exhibition_he_edit_mult'];
$subjects_en = $_POST['subjects_en_edit_mult'];
$subjects_he = $_POST['subjects_he_edit_mult'];
$keywords_en = $_POST['keywords_en_edit_mult'];
$keywords_he = $_POST['keywords_he_edit_mult'];
$year = $_POST['year_edit_mult'];
$sold = $_POST['sold_edit_mult'];

$columns_array = array("exhibition_he", "subjects_en", "subjects_he", "keywords_en", "keywords_he", "year", "sold");
$values_array = array($exhibition_he, $subjects_en, $subjects_he, $keywords_en, $keywords_he, $year, $sold);
$ids_array = explode(", ", $ids);

for ($i1=0; $i1 < count($values_array); $i1++) {
if ($values_array[$i1] != "") {
    for ($i2=0; $i2 < count($ids_array); $i2++) {

        // prepare statement for editing row values ($stmt1)
        $sql_string = "UPDATE paintings_catalog SET column=? WHERE id=?";
        $sql = str_replace("column", $columns_array[$i1], $sql_string);
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // bind submitted row values
        $stmt1->bind_param("si", $values_array[$i1], $ids_array[$i2]);

        // edit row values
        $stmt1->execute();
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your values you are replacing with than it's safe, if it's users value you are replacing with than it's NOT safe. In your case you are replacing with your predefined values which means that user has no way to alter them.

Short answer - for your case **SAFE**